# Robot names for robots.txt

Tags: wget, robots.txt

Suppose I have a website that uses `wget` to crawl other websites. I would like to provide website owners the chance of not being crawled by my website. Should they use the robot name `wget` in their `robots.txt` file, or do I have to create some other name?

Comment: Pretty sure `wget` respects the UA "wget" (unless the user forces it to ignore the robots file, of course). And obviously it'll respect "*" when appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common practice is to disallow all and to allow just the most popular UAs like this:

```
User-agent: Google
Disallow:


User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

So I think you don't have any problems with using `wget` that way

Answer (score 0):

It seems like websites that want to block robots will block them all with a wildcard, rather than selectively - there are so many User Agents out there, too many to list them all.

So as long as wget has a default user agent (which I think it does), I would stick with that.